# Switch in C programming

Tags: c

I did this code only for learning purpose. But while doing so I found a problem. Here x is constant integer,still compiler is giving me error. I am using gcc compiler. Please explain what is the reason of this error and how to avoid it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int const  x = 10;
int y = 20;
switch(y)
{
    case x:      //error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
    printf("value of x: %d\n",x);   
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: if its a constant, why not use `case 10:` instead, also you will need `default` case

Comment: @user1 For readability for instance. Remember magic numbers are bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the preprocessor as a workaround:

```
#define X 10
// ...
case X:
```

Comment: but as far as i know preprocessor is also constant not a constant qualifier

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate. Why post an answer?

Comment: although the original question is closely related to the one linked, I thought this answer (which is not a duplciate of another answer) still may be useful to ciscumvent the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

The grammar for a [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66k51h7a.aspx) in C is the following:

```
selection-statement:
switch ( expression ) statement
  labeled-statement:
  case constant-expression : statement
  default : statement
```

Therefore, you can only use constant expressions as "case value". [Constant expression is not the same as constant variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755524/example-of-something-which-is-and-is-not-a-constant-expression-in-c). In other words - sorry, but you cannot do that.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate. Why post an answer?

Comment: @RedX: Because answering this was easier than quicker for me than researching for duplicates. Nobody prevents you from voting this a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

*You* might know that `x` is a constant but the compiler cannot guarantee it: it is *still* possible to modify `x` in C. One way is by taking its address (via a pointer) and dereferencing it.

In C you can only switch on literal integral types; more formally, a *constant expression*.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate question. Why post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In this case , you have to use a `if` statement becasue  C's `switch()` 
 does not take an expression. It takes a constant.

Comment: switch() takes an expression. case xx: doesn't though.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate. Why post an answer?

Comment: sorry I didn't check. Could you mark it as duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

`case` statements need constants. You could accomplish something similar to what you're doing with a macro.

```
#define TEN 10
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int const  x = TEN;
int y = 20;
switch(y)
{
    case TEN:      //error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
    printf("value of x: %d\n",x);   
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: This is clearly a duplicate. Why post an answer?

Comment: Duplicate of what? `devnull` and `jev`'s answer came after mine. It's not a duplicate if it was first.

Comment: Of another qustion on the site, see the votes for close.

Comment: Oh, you mean the question's a duplicate? It didn't occur to me to check. I've flagged it.

Comment: That question's answer explains why but doesn't give a satisfactory solution IMHO @RedX.

Comment: Then maybe add an answer there? This is specially important as in future all clicks on this topic might be redirected there.