# What are the differences between constant expressions and nonmodifiable lvalues?

Tags: c

From C in a Nutshell:

> **Constant expressions**
>
> The  compiler  recognizes  constant  expressions  in  source  code
> and  replaces  them with their values. The resulting constant value
> must be representable in the expression’s type. You may use a constant
> expression wherever a simple constant is permitted.
>
> Operators in
> constant expressions are subject to the same rules as in other
> expressions. Because constant expressions are evaluated at translation
> time, though, they cannot contain function calls or operations that
> modify variables, such as assignments.

1. What are constant expressions? It doesn't define constant expressions
2. What are the differences between constant expressions and non-modifiable lvalues (e.g. array names, lvalues which have been declared with `const`)
3. Are constant expressions always non-lvalues?
4. Are non-modifiable lvalues constant expressions?

Comment: Any help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3755524/2173917

Comment: I think it's clear that the *important* difference is runtime vs translation time.

Comment: Think of constant expression as meaning _literal values_ or operations on literal values in this context.  A non-modifiable lvalue is a variable in memory (that's one way to see lvalues), which is defined as being `const`.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: "*which is defined as being `const`*" not necessarily, think of an array.

Comment: An array initializer list is not an array, and must be a constant expression.  A non-const array is a set of modifiable lvalues, not a constant expression.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: An array (in its whole) is a non-modifiable lvalue (See [C11 Std 6.3.2.1/1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1)).

Comment: I notice that you are keeping asking questions about definitions from different *books* about C. I don't know what is your intention. But the questions you always get are citing the **C standard**. Why won't you just grab a copy of it and try reading it when you have such a question? Also you almost never *accept* the answers.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Thanks. The link is very helpful!

Comment: @EugeneSh.  I apologize for my comments in the other post for what I was not meant to say

Answer (score 6):

> *What are constant expressions?*

§6.6- Constant Expression:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

One of the constraint on the constant expression is

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated<sup>115)</sup>.

---

> *What are the differences between constant expressions and nonmodifiable lvalues?*

Non modifiable lvalues are not constant expressions. **Non-modifiable values are lvalues that can't be used to modify an object**.

```
int const i = 5;
```

`i` is referring to a const object but it is an lvalue, a special kind of lvalue called non-modifiable lvalue.

Wherever standard says about "lvalue", it actually means "modifiable lvalue" (you won't find this in standard but for the sake of clarity)

Now let me explain it a bit more.

```
int x = 5;
int const *p;
```

`x` is a non const object and it is a modifiable lvalue. `p` is a pointer to a `const int` object.

```
p = &x;  // This will raise a warning though and hazardous to do.
```

Above assignment uses a qualification conversion to convert a value of type *pointer to `int`* into a value of type *pointer to `const int`*.
`*p` and `x` are two different expression referring to the same object. This abject can be modified using `x`

```
--x;
```

but this can't be done using `*p` as it is a non-modifiable lvalues.

```
--(*p); // Error
```

One more difference between a constant expression and a non-modifiable lvalue is

```
int const x = 5;
int *p;
/* Assigning address of a non-modifiable object */
p = &x      // Correct
/* Assigning address of a constant expression */
p = &5      // Wrong
```

> *Are constant expressions always non-lvalues?*

Yes, constant expressions are always *non-lvalues*, i.e rvalues.

> *Are nonmodifiable lvalues constant expressions?*

**No**.

Comment: any example where constant expression is not an `nonmodifiable lvalue`?

Comment: @PeterJ; Constant expression can never be an lvalue. A non-modifiable lvalue is an lvalue but it can't be used to modify the object it represent to. The expression `5` is a constant expression and it is an rvalue, not an lvalue (non-modifiable lvalue).

Comment: Thanks. "A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be." (1) How can I tell if an expression can be evaluated during translation or only runtime? (2) What does "a constant" refer to? Something different from "constant expression"?

Comment: "Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators". Why can't a constant expression contain any of those? Do them make an expression not "constant"?

Comment: @Tim: constant expression means "value calculations only". If a value is assigned somewhere, some incremented or decremented (`++`, `--`), then something is *variable* there and therefore the whole expression is not constant... Also, constant means "compile-time". Function calls occur as if at runtime (even though sometimes compiler *will* resolve those at compile-time, it is not ever required that even the simplest function calls will be inlined).

Answer (score 4):

1. Constant expressions are defined in [C11 6.6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6):

   > **Description**
   >
   > [2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p2). A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.
   >
   > Constraints
   >
   > [3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p3) Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or [comma operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737634/c-comma-operator), except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.115)
   >
   > [4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p4) Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable values for its type.

   There are several types of constant expressions which might be allowed in a place. There are constant expressions that evaluate to

   - an arithmetic constant expression,

     - a special case of this is *integer constant expression*, which is allowed for example as the size of a (statically allocated) array, or a bitfield width.
   - a null pointer constant,
   - an address constant, or
   - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant expression.
2. lvalues or locator values (potentially) designate objects. You can take the address of an lvalue. The difference between a modifiable and non-modifiable lvalue is that the latter cannot be used as the left-hand side of an assignment. Or, [C11 6.3.2.1p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1):

   > A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const- qualified type.

   A non-modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that is not modifiable.

   Constant expressions are just... values. They do not reside in memory - there  is no address for number 42 - `&42` is meaningless.
3. constant expressions are thus always non-lvalues. They do not designate *objects*. You cannot take the address of `6 * 9`.
4. no, but... lvalues of array types implicitly decay into pointers-to-arrays, and these *are* address constants. However as they're thusly converted they stop being lvalues.

Comment: Thanks. "Constant expressions are just... values. They do not reside in memory". Not even readonly part of the memory? Then where do constant expressions reside?

Comment: @Tim the number 6 can be written on paper (then it is an object), but the *idea* of 6 doesn't have a place. Well, the constant expressions reside in memory within the *compiler*; but if you think about a constant expression in a bitfield, say, or a size of an array - the number itself might not be stored directly in the executable at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are more than one *complex* questions, let me try to answer it in a simple way (*mostly by blatantly copy-pasting from the standard, just creation a retational connection on my own*).

> *1. What are constant expressions?*

`C11`, chapter §6.5, `Expressions`,

> An *expression* is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies computation of a
>   value, or that designates an object or a function, or that generates side effects, or that
>   performs a combination thereof.

chapter 6.6, `Constant expressions`

> constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and
>   accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

and, P4

> Each constant expression shall evaluate to a constant that is in the range of representable
>   values for its type.

and, for `Lvalues`, chapter §6.3.2,

> An lvalue is an expression (with an object type other than void) that **potentially
>   designates an object**

and, for an ***object***, §3.15,

> **object**
>
> region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent
>   values

Some constant expressions, such as arrays (array names), string literals or address constants, are lvalues. Otherwise, for the whole range of non-modifiable lvalues, consists of constant object (or object references) and constant expressions.

Comment: ... and arrays.

Comment: Is adress constant `&5` lvalue?

Comment: @haccks umm..not sure if i'm missing something, but how is `&5` is address constant? `An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static
storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator;`...so, this example is not applicable in this case, right sir?

Answer (score -1):

Constant expression is the expression which value is known (can be evaluated) during the compilation

examaples

```
int a = 5+5+3;  //5 + 5 +3 
char []= "Hello"; // string literal "hello"
```

Not modificable lvalues are constant objects & constant expessions

Exmaples

```
const char c;
c = '3';

'3' = c;
```

Modifiable lvalue has to be addressable (ie you can get their address using &) and assignable ie they can be on the left side of the assignment operator. The only exception are register variables which do no have the address.

Comment: ... and arrays.

Comment: I did not included arrays as there is no language construction allowing such a assignment. Before C99 same was with structs.

Comment: *Not modificable lvalues are constant objects & constant expessions* : No, they are not.